# Telnet to the EchoServer Grizzly sample application

Tags: java, nio, grizzly

I've been working on a server application that will over time receive quite a lot of connections. In order to be able to handle this I have been implementing a non blocking design using the standard java NIO classes. But there are a lot of details to handle, and I would much prefer to use some sort of framework. Preferably I would like to use Spring Integration but I have not been able to find some simple, working examples.

In stead I am now evaluating the Grizzly framework, which seems to offer the functionality I need. I implemented their [EchoServer example](http://grizzly.java.net/nonav/docs/docbkx2.0/html/quickstart.html) but found that I was unable to Telnet to the server and have the results echoed back to me on the console. Their EchoClient application works as expected.

In my case I cannot make any assumptions about the clients trying to connect to me, so I have to be able to support everything from simple telnet clients to NIO clients. Is Grizzly able to do this, and if so how?

Comment: As an aside, if you haven't already, it might be worth taking a look at the [Netty Framework](http://netty.io/) - it's another framework for building NIO clients and servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you're working with is based on special input format implemented by StringFilter. The StringFilter decodes/encodes Strings as sequence of bytes with a string-length prefix.
For sure telnet doesn't use the same format to encode Strings that's why server doesn't echo the data back.
In order to make the server work with telnet - just remove a StringFilter from the server's FilterChain (comment out this line):

```
//          filterChainBuilder.add(new StringFilter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I should have guessed that. I was in a hurry to try out Grizzly, and the StringFilter thing simply looked like some character encoding boilerplate code. I did not realize there was a length encoding involved as well. Thanks for your help!